# Not Sure How to Resolve "Contextstack overflow" error

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I have some data that looks like the following:

```
UniqueID MonthYear Count2 CCount
402ABC   OCT2018   5      1               
402ABC   NOV2018   5      2               
402ABC   DEC2018   5      3               
402ABC   JAN2019   5      4              
402ABC   FEB2019   5      5               
495DEF   FEB2019  10      1      
495DEF   MAR2019  10      2      
495DEF   APR2019  10      3      
495DEF   MAY2019  10      4     
495DEF   JUN2019  10      5     
495DEF   AUG2019  10      6     
495DEF   SEP2019  10      7     
495DEF   DEC2019  10      8    
495DEF   JAN2020  10      9    
495DEF   FEB2020  10     10
```

What I want is to be able to create a new column titled "Corrected" that finds the last instance of a UniqueID.  Ideally, the new data would look like the following:

```
UniqueID MonthYear Count2 CCount Corrected
402ABC   OCT2018   5      1      0         
402ABC   NOV2018   5      2      0          
402ABC   DEC2018   5      3      0         
402ABC   JAN2019   5      4      0        
402ABC   FEB2019   5      5      1         
495DEF   FEB2019  10      1      0
495DEF   MAR2019  10      2      0
495DEF   APR2019  10      3      0
495DEF   MAY2019  10      4      0
495DEF   JUN2019  10      5      0
495DEF   AUG2019  10      6      0
495DEF   SEP2019  10      7      0
495DEF   DEC2019  10      8      0
495DEF   JAN2020  10      9      0
495DEF   FEB2020  10     10      1
```

I had a series of nested ifelse functions used to create the "Corrected" column in my data frame.  The nested chunk looked like the following:

```
smd$Corrected=ifelse(smd$MonthYear=="OCT2018" & smd$Count2==1, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="OCT2018" & smd$Count2 >1, 0,ifelse(
    
                     smd$MonthYear=="NOV2018" & smd$Count2==1, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="NOV2018" & smd$Count2==smd$CCount, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="NOV2018" & smd$Count2!=smd$CCount, 0,ifelse(
          
                     smd$MonthYear=="DEC2018" & smd$Count2==1, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="DEC2018" & smd$Count2==smd$CCount, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="DEC2018" & smd$Count2!=smd$CCount, 0,ifelse(
………………………


                     smd$MonthYear=="MAY2020" & smd$Count2==1, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="MAY2020" & smd$Count2==smd$CCount, 1,ifelse(
                     smd$MonthYear=="MAY2020" & smd$Count2!=smd$CCount, 0,0
                                                                
             )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

I understand this was not the most elegant solution, but it worked for my purposes.  This is just one part of a larger analysis I was running.  The analysis was updated once every month and I added a new chunk to this code each time I updated it.  Today, when I attempted to update the code, I got the following error:

```
Error: contextstack overflow at line 66
```

Doing a little bit of research, I learned that this error pops up when you use too many nested ifelse statements.  Other questions on StackOverflow suggested I use either sapply or mapply to rewrite this code.  I tried a couple of apply functions here to rewrite my code, but nothing seemed to work quite right.

Can anyone help suggesting how I would rewrite my code to not use all the nested ifelse functions?  Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you don't need all the conditioning on `MonthYear`, or if you do you could say `smd$MonthYear %in% c("OCT2018", "NOV2018" ...)`, that could dramatically reduce the complexity of your `ifelse`

Comment: Omg, I'm a moron!  Thank you so much for this answer!  Worked like a charm!  If you click "Answer the question" below and write the same thing, I can award you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, my suggestion would be to remove the line-by-line conditioning on `MonthYear`, it seems like you don't really need to do that.

If it is necessary to condition on `MonthYear`, it may be better to use

```
smd$MonthYear %in% c("OCT2018", "NOV2018" ...)
```

in your `ifelse`.